# PCRE is not matching utf8 characters

Tags: c, utf-8, pcre

I'm compiling a PCRE pattern with utf8 flag enabled and am trying to match a utf8 `char*` string against it, but it is not matching and `pcre_exec` returns negative. I'm passing the subject length as 65 to `pcre_exec` which is the number of characters in the string. I believe it expects the number of bytes so I have tried with increasing the argument till 70 but still get the same result. I don't know what else is making the match fail. Please help before I shoot myself.

(If I try without the flag `PCRE_UTF8` however, it matches but the offset vector[1] is 30 which is index of the character just before a unicode character in my input string)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "pcre.h"
#include <pcre.h>               /* PCRE lib        NONE  */
#include <stdio.h>              /* I/O lib         C89   */
#include <stdlib.h>             /* Standard Lib    C89   */
#include <string.h>             /* Strings         C89   */
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
   pcre *reCompiled;

   int pcreExecRet;
   int subStrVec[30];
   const char *pcreErrorStr;
   int pcreErrorOffset; 
   char* aStrRegex = "(\\?\\w+\\?\\s*=)?\\s*(call|exec|execute)\\s+(?<spName>\\w+)(" 
                                     // params can be an empty pair of parenthesis or have parameters inside them as well.
                                     "\\(\\s*(?<params>[?\\w,]+)\\s*\\)"
                                     // paramList along with its parenthesis is optional below so a SP call can be just "exec sp_name" for a stored proc call without any parameters.
                                     ")?";
    reCompiled = pcre_compile(aStrRegex, 0, &pcreErrorStr, &pcreErrorOffset, NULL);
    if(reCompiled == NULL) {
      printf("ERROR: Could not compile '%s': %s\n", aStrRegex, pcreErrorStr);
      exit(1);
    } 

    char* line = "?rt?=call SqlTxFunctionTesting(?înFîéld?,?outField?,?inOutField?)";
    pcreExecRet = pcre_exec(reCompiled,
                            NULL,
                            line, 
                            65,  // length of string
                            0,                      // Start looking at this point
                            0,                      // OPTIONS
                            subStrVec,
                            30);                    // Length of subStrVec

   printf("\nret=%d",pcreExecRet);

   //int substrLen = pcre_get_substring(line, subStrVec, pcreExecRet, 1, &mantissa);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
char * q= "î";
printf("%d, %s", q[0], q);
```

Output:
63, ?

2) You must rebuild PCRE with PCRE_BUILD_PCRE16 (or 32) and PCRE_SUPPORT_UTF. And use pcre16.lib and/or pcre16.dll. Then you can try this code:

```
  pcre16 *reCompiled;
  int pcreExecRet;
  int subStrVec[30];
  const char *pcreErrorStr;
  int pcreErrorOffset;  
  wchar_t* aStrRegex = L"(\\?\\w+\\?\\s*=)?\\s*(call|exec|execute)\\s+(?<spName>\\w+)(" 
                                     // params can be an empty pair of paranthesis or have parameters inside them as well.
                                     L"\\(\\s*(?<params>[?,\\w\\p{L}]+)\\s*\\)"
                                     // paramList along with its paranthesis is optional below so a SP call can be just "exec sp_name" for a stored proc call without any parameters.
                                     L")?";
   reCompiled = pcre16_compile((PCRE_SPTR16)aStrRegex, PCRE_UTF8, &pcreErrorStr, &pcreErrorOffset, NULL);
   if(reCompiled == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR: Could not compile '%s': %s\n", aStrRegex, pcreErrorStr);
    exit(1);
   } 

  const wchar_t* line = L"?rt?=call SqlTxFunctionTesting(  ?inField?,?outField?,?inOutField?,?fd?  )";
  const wchar_t* mantissa=new wchar_t[wcslen(line)];
  pcreExecRet = pcre16_exec(reCompiled,
                            NULL,
                            (PCRE_SPTR16)line, 
                            wcslen(line),  // length of string
                            0,                      // Start looking at this point
                            0,                      // OPTIONS
                            subStrVec,
                            30);                    // Length of subStrVec

 printf("\nret=%d",pcreExecRet);
 for (int i=0;i<pcreExecRet;i++){
     int substrLen = pcre16_get_substring((PCRE_SPTR16)line, subStrVec, pcreExecRet, i, (PCRE_SPTR16 *)&mantissa);
     wprintf(L"\nret string=%s, length=%i\n",mantissa,substrLen);
 }
```

3) \w = [0-9A-Z_a-z]. It doesn't contains unicode symbols.
4) This can really help: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/215-how-to-use-unicode-code-points-properties-blocks-and-scripts-in-regular-expressions/
5) from PCRE 8.33 source (pcre_exec.c:2251)

```
/* Find out if the previous and current characters are "word" characters.
It takes a bit more work in UTF-8 mode. Characters > 255 are assumed to
be "non-word" characters. Remember the earliest consulted character for
partial matching. */
```